# User informaiton list not updaing SIP address

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, user-profile-service

We have some users whose SIP address will not update using any of the SharePoint OOB methods. I have to force the update using powershell:

```
$web = $site.RootWeb 
$list = $web.Lists["User Information List"] 
$user = $list.Items | where {$_["Account"] -eq "i:0#.w|domain\user account"} 
$user["SipAddress"] = "user@some-email.com"
```

I tried deleteolddatabases, all the various UPS syncs, etc. and nothing worked. It appears it is only the SIP address that won't update. I have read that this can happen if the account is not flagged as active but I don't know how to tell if an account in the user information list is flagged as inactive.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this in a production environment, but in my test environment it works. After you get the valid `$user` try this:

```
$user["IsActive"] = $true
$user.Update()
```

Then you can force the sync timer job or just wait an hour. Setting the IsActive flag should cause the timer job to update the offending records.

Comment: The user account was already active so it didn't resolve the SIP address issues but I marked your response as the answer because it did show me how to check the status of the user. Thanks.